# How to use support for Windows path separator into a Regex?

Tags: regex, go, filepath

I have the following code to check if `someConfigFilePath` value, which comes from configuration file, matches the current `filePath` and must support Windows and Unix-like platforms:

```
regexp.MatchString(someConfigFilePath, filePath)
```

The regex works in Unix-like platforms, but not in Windows. After some debugging, I could find out that I need to do something like this before, then regex works inside Windows:

```
ps := string(os.PathSeparator)
someConfigFilePathReplaced = strings.ReplaceAll(someConfigFilePath, ps, "\\\\")
```

**Question is: which would be the best way to handle this kind of situation, using Golang, to accomplish support in regex regarding the path separator, for all OS platforms?**

P.S.: All file paths were already handled by `path/filepath.FromSlash`

Comment: Did you mean `filepath.ToSlash`? (`FromSlash` replaces each slash (`/`) character in path with a separator character but in your case it looks like you want to go the other direction and convert separators to `/` so you can use a regex which assumes `/`).

Comment: I don't think so. My question is to get a suggestion on how to implement the regex coverage over different OS, since I had to do the `ReplaceAll` trick to work inside Windows

Comment: That is one approach; the other is to use `filepath.ToSlash` to alter the `filePath` to use slashes as separators (if on windows; it will have no impact on an OS that uses slashes). It might help if you provide some example data (`c:\somepath\file.txt` is not going to match `/somepath/file.txt` without significant manipulation so I'm not sure how your config file will be OS neutral unless you are using relative paths?).